# Edit Mozilla configuration file in Python

Tags: python

Settings for the Mozilla Firefox browser my be changed by entering `about:config` in the address bar, which will open a configuration file. I would like to be able to edit, delete and add parameters to this file in Python. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The configuration files used in firefox are actually a couple of javascript files that you can find under the profile directory: `prefs.js` and `user.js`.

You can use python to append lines to those files (`user.js` recommended) like:

```
user_pref(<preference>, <value>)
```

However, I don't really think is a good idea to use python for this.

Comment: Well, those files are really just text, which Python is well known to be good with, so why not?

Comment: @JoaoFigueiredo They are not only text files, but also javascript files. A script to parse them should work and you can go with that solution if you feel comfortable with it, but I think it would be also error-prone and difficult to maintain depending on what firefox stores in those files.

Answer (score 0):

You can check 
[Firefox Profiles](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey)
to get to the OS dependent profile,

also, 
[here](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey) is a duplicate question to point you in the right direction.

Also, maybe 
[this Javascript Python bridge](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-spidermonkey) will better assist you editing the files.